# JavaFX: how to style scroll bar in TableView to look like standard Windows Scroll Bar?

Tags: javafx, tableview, scrollbar

I am trying to style TableView scroll bar to look like standard Windows Scroll Bar: that is, it should look like:
[image: standard windows scroll bar]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC510545.png))</sub>

in this text area text box. Please help.

Comment: Do you have one single target os version (win7 as on the picture)?

Comment: If you style the scroll bar to look like a standard windows scroll bar then if it is ran on other platforms it won't look right there.

Comment: I want to style scroll bar like on attached picture. The style of scrollbar should be applied only on Windows platform (Windows 7 scroll bar is sufficient). I want to style scrollbar in Javafx TableView but the whole app is Swing Type but i will use JFXPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this will be possible with pure CSS, so I guess the option you have is to create your own skin, as the [scrollbar is skinnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#setSkin-javafx.scene.control.Skin-).

As you probably don't want to set the skin for each scrollbar individually, make sure you set your skin in your application's css:

```
.scroll-bar {
   -fx-skin: "org.foo.bar.MyWindowsScrollBarSkin";
}
```